# ¿Como hago para que el div con Bootstrap me ocupe el ancho de la pantalla?

Tags: bootstrap

A ver si me podéis ayudar. Estoy intentando hacer un plantilla para una web con un menú lateral. Quiero que el div horizontal de arriba me ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla pero no logro conseguirlo como podéis apreciar en la imagen.
[image: div]
Si al div le pongo col-12, se me sale de la pantalla, por lo que realmente no me lo ajusta a ella.

[image: con col-12]
Os dejo el código por si alguien me puede ayudar. Lo que quiero conseguir es que la imagen se quede justo al final y que esa barra ocupe todo el ancho pero sin pasarse.

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body{font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
     background: #fafafa}
p{font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.7em;
 color: #999;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus{
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.navbar{
 padding: 15px 10px;
 background: #fff;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.navbar-btn{
 box-shadow: none;
 outline: none!important;
 border: none;
}

.line{
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
#sidebar.active{
 margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header{
 padding: 20px;
 background: #6d7fcc;
}
#sidebar ul.components{
 padding: 20px 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p{
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a{
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}
a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a.download{
 background: #fff;
 color: #7386D5;
}
a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
 position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

@media(maz-width:768px){
 #sidebar{margin-left: -250px;}
 #sidebar.active{
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
 #sidebarCollapse span{
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

    <title>bootstrap 4 sidebar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
   <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
     <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>BOOTSTRAP SIDEBAR</h3>
     </div>
     
     
     <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>Dummy Heading</p>
      <li class="active">
       <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
       <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
        <li>
         <a href="#">home1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">home2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">home3</a>
        </li>
       </ul> 
      </li>
      
      <li>
       <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Page</a>
       <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
        <li>
         <a href="#">page1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">page2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">page3</a>
        </li>
       </ul> 
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     
     <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
      <li>
       <a href="#" class="download">Download code</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#" class="article">article</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="content col-12">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
     
     <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> <span>toggle sidebar</span>
     </button>
     
  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <img src="img/logo.png" width="100%" alt="">
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    </div>
   </div>
    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click',function(){
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
   });
  });  
 </script>
    
    
    
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ese `sidebar` se supone que esta oculto y al clickear en `toogle` se abre?

Comment: Si, me acabo de dar cuenta que al cerrar el sidebar se centra, pero lo que quiero conseguir es que ese div tanto al estar abierto como cerrado ocupe lo mismo y no se desplace.

Comment: ok te preparate un ejemplo

Comment: la idea es que el `header` que contiene el boton `slide toggle` quede fijo y que el `slidebar` aparezca y desaparezca quedando el header fijo?

Comment: Exacto! me gustaría que el logo que tengo en la header se quedara siempre visible en la esquina derecha, por lo que me gustaría que se quedara fijo y sliderbar se pueda ocultar y mostrar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo te recomendaría es quitarle al la navegación el `col-12` y agregarle un estilo con un `width: 100%;` el cual te lo hará ocupar toda la pantalla. Aquí te dejo el código funcionando.

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body{font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
     background: #fafafa}
p{font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.navbar{
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.navbar-btn{
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none!important;
    border: none;
}

.line{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
#sidebar.active{
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header{
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}
#sidebar ul.components{
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}
a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a.download{
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}
a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

@media(maz-width:768px){
    #sidebar{margin-left: -250px;}
    #sidebar.active{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

    <title>bootstrap 4 sidebar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
   <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>BOOTSTRAP SIDEBAR</h3>
        </div>
        
        
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <p>Dummy Heading</p>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">home1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">home2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">home3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Page</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">page1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">page2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">page3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="download">Download code</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="article">article</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="content" style="width: 100%;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> <span>toggle sidebar</span>
        </button>
        
  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active">
              <img src="img/logo.png" width="100%" alt="">
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    </div>
   </div>
    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click',function(){
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            });
        });  
    </script>
    
    
    
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```